# How to get a WinForm synchronization context or schedule on a WinForm thread

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, system.reactive, synchronizationcontext

I have a winform application, and an observable set up like this:

```
Form form = new Form();
Label lb = new Label();
form.Controls.Add(lb);

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Subscribe(l => lb.Text = l.ToString());

Application.Run(form);
```

This doesn't work, since the `l => lb.Text = l.ToString()` will not be run on the main thread which created the form, but I cannot figure out how to make it run on this thread. I assume, that I should use `IObservable.SubscribeOn` which takes either an `IScheduler` or a `SynchronizationContext`, but I don't know how to get the synchronizationcontext of the main thread, and the only Schedulers I could find were the static properties of `Scheduler`, such as `Scheduler.CurrentThread`, `Immediate`, `NewThread`, `TaskPool` and `ThreadPool`, none of which worked.

My Rx version is 1.0.10621.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just after I post the question, I find the solution:

```
Form form = new Form();
Label lb = new Label();
form.Controls.Add(lb);

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
          .Subscribe(l => lb.Text = l.ToString());

Application.Run(form);
```

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx) link was helpful. Two notes:

- Not all threads have a synchronization context, but the first form that gets created on a thread will set a synchronization context for that thread, so the UI thread always has one.
- The correct method is `ObserveOn`, not `SubscribeOn`. At the moment, I don't know enough about this to know why, so any links in the comments would be appreciated.

---

edit: Thanks to the first part of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2009/11/21/observable-context-observable-subscribeon-and-observable-observeon.aspx) link, I now understand more about the difference between `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn`. In short:

- An observable, which observes on a synchronization context will call the IObserver methods (`OnNext` and friends) from that context. In my example, I observe on the main/UI thread, so therefore I get no cross thread exceptions
- `SubscribeOn` is a little more complicated, so here is an example: Concat takes a number of observables and combines them to one long observable. Once an observable calls `OnCompleted`, the combined observable will dispose of that subscription, and subscribe to the next observable. This all happens on the thread that called `OnCompleted`, but there can be some problems with subscribing to observables, that were created by `Observable.FromEvent`, e.g. Silverlight will throw if you add an event handler from another thread than the UI thread, and WinForms and WPF will throw if you add a event handlers from multiple different threads. `SubscribeOn` will let you control the thread on which your observable hooks up to the underlying event.

Comment: `SubscribeOn` only sets which thread the actual subscribing happens on, whereas `ObserveOn` determines which thread the `OnNext` calls get executed.  For comparison with events, `SubscribeOn` is like making you only add event handlers on the main thread, but `ObserveOn` makes sure the event handling routine gets called on the right thread.

Comment: @Gideon: Thanks. I edited my answer to reflect my improved understanding, but your comments sums it all up very well.

Comment: If you have a reference to System.Reactive.Windows.Forms.dll you can do .ObserveOn(form) and it will do the equivalent of Control.Invoke.

Comment: @Anderson: Ah, I had seen code that used the form as an argument - except I remembered it as SubscribeOn instead of ObserveOn - but since I couldn't find that overload, and most of the tutorials I had seen were 1 or 2 years old, I had thought that that part of the API had been deprecated, and was no longer available. Thanks, this makes it even nicer.

Comment: It works for winform. But just curious, does SynchronizationContext.Current necessarily mean UI thread?

Comment: @liang If you call `SynchronizationContext.Current` from the main thread of a UI application, it will be the main UI thread. Otherwise, it will be the synchronization context of the currently running thread (probably just `null`).