# What's the difference between SubscribeOn and ObserveOn

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I just discovered `SubscribeOn`, which makes me wonder if I should be using that instead of `ObserveOn`. Google took me [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/6944f097-00f4-42ad-8f19-d01d1aa939f4/) and [here](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2011/07/24/Rx-Using-the-ObserveOn-and-SubscribeOn-operators.aspx), but neither have helped me grok the difference: it seems incredibly subtle.

*(In my context, I've got events 'coming up' on a non-gui thread, and I need to switch over to a gui thread before using the event data to update controls).*

Comment: `SubscribeOn` solves a problem in which adding event handlers from multiple threads in Winforms or WPF will cause exceptions.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back and asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417978/) question about it. I think the responses (including the comments) there will answer your question. To summarize:

- If you want to update controls on a gui thread, use `ObserveOn`. If you reference `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms.dll` you get the `.ObserveOn(form)` which is handy.
- `SubscribeOn` controls the thread on which the actual call to subscribe happens. The problem solved here is that WinForms and WPF will throw exceptions if you add event handlers from multiple different threads.

Also, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2009/11/21/observable-context-observable-subscribeon-and-observable-observeon.aspx) post was very helpful in figuring out the relationship between `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn`.

Answer (score 65):

It helped me to understand this by thinking of `SubscribeOn` as setting the thread being "passed up" the chain and `ObserveOn` as setting the thread "passed down" the chain.

[image: Subscriber thread "passed up" and Observer thread "passed down"]

The code below uses named threads which you can play with.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";

IScheduler thread1 = new NewThreadScheduler(x => new Thread(x) { Name = "Thread1" });
IScheduler thread2 = new NewThreadScheduler(x => new Thread(x) { Name = "Thread2" });

Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subscribing on " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    o.OnNext(1);
    return Disposable.Create(() => {});
})
.SubscribeOn(thread1)
.ObserveOn(thread2)
.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Observing '" + x + "' on " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name));
```

The output of the above is:

`Subscribing on Thread1
 Observing 1 on Thread2`

It's also interesting to see that when you comment out the `SubscribeOn` line, the output is:

`Subscribing on Main
 Observing 1 on Thread2`

Because by default the subscription "passes up" whichever thread was running (`Main` here). Then the `ObserveOn` "passes down" `Thread2`.

If you instead comment out the `ObserveOn` line, the output is:

`Subscribing on Thread1
 Observing 1 on Thread1`

Because we "pass up" the subscription on `Thread1`, and by default this same thread is "passed down" and used to run the observation.

In a GUI context, to keep things responsive you want the least amount of work done on the GUI thread but you **need** the subscription done on the GUI thread (to synchronise UI updates). So you want to .ObserveOn the GUI thread.

Answer (score 10):

The differences basically is that subscribeOn force the whole pipeline to be processed by another thread, but with observerOn only the steps in your pipeline define after observerOn will run in another thread only after you set it will be executed in another thread.

```
    Observable.just(1) 
              .map ---> executed in io thread
              .filter ---> executed in io thread
              .subscribeOn(Scheduers.io)
              .subscribe()
```

All the steps of the pipeline will be executed in another thread.

```
 Observable.just(1) 
              .map ---> executed in Main thread
              .filter ---> executed in Main thread
              .observerOn(Scheduers.io)
              .map ---> executed in New thread
              .filter ---> executed in New thread
              .subscribe()
```