# 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.NewThread' is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, system.reactive

I am trying to retrieve data from database using Entity-Framework 5.0 Code fast and Reactive Extensions (Rx). I am writing following code for that.

```
var obs = DataContext.GetDataContext().BreakdownCauses.OrderBy(x => x.Cause).ToObservable(Scheduler.NewThread);
obs.SubscribeOnDispatcher().Subscribe(x => ItemCollection.Add(slow(x))); 

BreakdownCause slow(BreakdownCause cs)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        return cs;
    }
```

But it show me this warning :

```
'System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.NewThread' is obsolete: 'This property is no longer supported due to refactoring of the API surface and elimination of platform-specific dependencies. Please add a reference to the System.Reactive.PlatformServices assembly for your target platform and use NewThreadScheduler.Default to obtain an instance of this scheduler type. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260866 for more information.'
```

And at RunTime I get an Exception :

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Please suggests me how can i use Reactive Extensions (Rx) properly in EF5.0 Code fast in my WPF application or any batter way to call database asynchronously.

Comment: Did you try changing your code based on the message given to you?

Comment: ya. Now warning is goes away. But Exception is still alive.

Comment: See the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579237/whats-the-difference-between-subscribeon-and-observeon. It seems `SubscribeOnDispatcher` does not necessarily marshal your call to `ItemCollection.Add` back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call ObserveOnDispatcher instead of SubscribeOnDispatcher. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/7bc192cc-6a81-4607-908f-041c1306394f/).