# How to call back async function from Rx Subscribe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I would like to call back an async function within an Rx subscription.

E.g. like that:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly Service _service = new Service();

    public ReplaySubject<string> Results = new ReplaySubject<string>();

    public void Trigger()
    {
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Subscribe(async _ => await RunAsync());
    }

    public Task RunAsync()
    {
        return _service.DoAsync();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public async Task<string> DoAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => Do());
    }

    private static string Do()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid!");
        return "foobar";
    }
}

[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var sut = new Consumer();
    sut.Trigger();
    var result = await sut.Results.FirstAsync();
}
```

What needs to be done, in order to catch the exception properly?

Comment: I just figured that I can put async at the first place. But unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem I am faced with. I will post a more explicit example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to subscribe an observer as async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814805/is-there-a-way-to-subscribe-an-observer-as-async)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't want to pass an `async` method to `Subscribe`, because that will create an `async void` method. Do your best to avoid `async void`.

In your case, I *think* what you want is to call the `async` method for each element of the sequence and then cache all the results. In that case, use `SelectMany` to call the `async` method for each element, and `Replay` to cache (plus a `Connect` to get the ball rolling):

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly Service _service = new Service();

    public IObservable<string> Trigger()
    {
        var connectible = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
            .SelectMany(_ => RunAsync())
            .Replay();
        connectible.Connect();
        return connectible;
    }

    public Task<string> RunAsync()
    {
        return _service.DoAsync();
    }
}
```

I changed the `Results` property to be returned from the `Trigger` method instead, which I think makes more sense, so the test now looks like:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var sut = new Consumer();
    var results = sut.Trigger();
    var result = await results.FirstAsync();
}
```

Comment: That is an awesome solution. Thanks Stephen.

Comment: What if you want to catch exceptions thrown from RunAsync? What I got is:
    obs.SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => RunAsync()).Catch(Observable.Empty<string>()))

Is there a better way?

Comment: @VictorGrigoriu: I recommend you ask your own question and tag it with `system.reactive`.

Comment: This solution does not preserve the ordering of results (just in case a reader is trying to achieve that). To preserve ordering look at the answers below.

Comment: And here's @Victor Grigoriu's follow-up question (with an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/29427680/68955

Answer (score 46):

Ana Betts' answer works in most scenarios, but if you want to block the stream while waiting for the async function to finish you need something like this:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(asyncMethod))
          .Concat()
          .Subscribe();
```

Or:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Select(_ => Observable.Defer(() => asyncMethod().ToObservable()))
          .Concat()
          .Subscribe();
```

Comment: It's another use case but very interesting though.

Comment: You must be very careful with this approach. If your async handler throws an exception, the subscription will be terminated, and your handle will stop receiving events. Basically, if you need asynchronous processing of observable events, you have to queue them and consume by a separate background task. There is no way around it - I learned that hard way.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/459

Answer (score 22):

Change this to:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .SelectMany(async _ => await RunAsync())
    .Subscribe();
```

Subscribe doesn't keep the async operation inside the Observable.

Comment: Thanks Paul, for your suggestion. Very interesting. Do you have something where I can read a little bit further about that?

Comment: Note for others using this solution, if you need keep the order just replace `SelectMany` with `Select` and then `.Concat` (similar to reijerh's answer).

Comment: This will produce an observable sequence of unfinished tasks. What do you do with them next? Your "subscriber" does nothing. All the tasks hang unobserved, no control over exceptions/termination. This is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Building on reijerh's answer, I created an extension method.

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<TResult>(this IObservable<TResult> source, Func<Task> action) =>
            source.Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(action))
                .Concat()
                .Subscribe();
```

If I understand this correctly, it should block until the async task finishes. But it will allow you to call `SubscribeAsync` and pass in your task. In my opinion this makes it a little more readable.

```
WhenSomethingHappened
    .SubscribeAsync(async () => { 
        await DoFirstAsyncThing(); 
        await DoSecondAsyncThing(); 
    });
```