# Rx: subscribe with async function and ignore errors

Tags: asynchronous, system.reactive

I want to call an async function for each item in an observable. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23006852/116818), the solution is to use `SelectMany`. However, if the async method throws, the subscription will terminate. I have the following solution, which seems to work:

```cs
obs.SelectMany(x => Observable
    .FromAsync(() => RunAsync())
    .Catch(Observable.Empty<string>()));
```

Is there a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard way to be able to observe the exceptions that occur in your `RunAsync` call, and that's using `.Materialize()`.

The `.Materialize()` method turns an `IObservable<T>` sequence into a `IObservable<Notification<T>>` sequence where you can reason against the `OnNext`, `OnError`, and `OnCompleted` calls.

I wrote this query:

```
var obs = Observable.Range(0, 10);

obs
    .SelectMany(x =>
        Observable
            .FromAsync(() => RunAsync())
            .Materialize())
    .Where(x => x.Kind != NotificationKind.OnCompleted)
    .Select(x => x.HasValue ? x.Value : (x.Exception.Message + "!"))
    .Subscribe(x => x.Dump());
```

With this supporting code:

```
private int counter = 0;
private Random rnd = new Random();

private System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> RunAsync()
{
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.3)
        {
            throw new Exception(counter.ToString());
        }
        return counter.ToString();
    });
}
```

When I run it I get this kind of output:

```
2
4
5
1!
6
7
3!
10
8!
9
```

Each of the lines ending in `!` are calls to `RunAsync` that resulted in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OnErrorResumeNext.

```
obs.SelectMany(x => Observable
    .FromAsync(() => RunAsync())
    .OnErrorResumeNext(Observable.Empty<string>()));
```

Comment: Right, but Catch gives me the opportunity to log the exception.

Comment: That's true, but could also be achieved with a Do().
Anyway, catch is probably the better choice, because OnErrorResumeNext executes the empty sequence also in case of successful termination.