# Rx how to throw Exception from Observable.FromAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have a design where we inject a RX Subject into a class that will call OnNext on the injected Subject (which is bad I know, lets not go there). This subject will need to call async/await code in the Subscribe method that will be called when the OnNext triggers. I know this is not cool so we need to do something like this [Rx: subscribe with async function and ignore errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427680/rx-subscribe-with-async-function-and-ignore-errors) where we use `Observable.FromAsync`

But what I need to trap is if any exceptions occur, they should bubble up to the outer class that called OnNext (where the subject class was injected), and I need to deal with that and start something again, but wish to reuse the same original subject passed in. Essentially I DO NOT wish to to ever raise OnError/OnCompleted on the subject that is injected into the class that calls OnNext

If I use code like this, I get the semmantics I want

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static CompositeDisposable disp = new CompositeDisposable();
        public static Subject<string> _subject = new Subject<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427680/rx-subscribe-with-async-function-and-ignore-errors
            _subject
                 .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
                    throw new Exception("bad juju");
                });


            var consumer = new Consumer(_subject);
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                consumer.Consume(CancellationToken.None);

            });
     
            Console.ReadKey();
            disp.Dispose();

        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {
        private readonly Subject<string> _subject;

        public Consumer(Subject<string> subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }

        public void Consume(CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _subject.OnNext(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"consumer saw {e.Message}");
                Consume(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where I get this sort of output (which is what I want)

```
consumer saw bad juju
7f5ef1971c6a421ea416110fa3473f5c
consumer saw bad juju
cdb63e6ef84144f7aac570e067566ad3
consumer saw bad juju
3947946907cc4be996adc2a7060a8962
consumer saw bad juju
bab899eb59ce4490918f1115eb0bde76
consumer saw bad juju
473e041924424906be0ccd9c624d90c4
consumer saw bad juju
8459956d2d5f494181a07526a2b9b9e2
```

But when I attempt to use the `Observable.FromAsync` where I introduce a random Exception, I only ever see my `OnNext` called once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    
    class Program
    {

        static CompositeDisposable disp = new CompositeDisposable();
        public static Subject<string> _subject = new Subject<string>();

        private static int counter = 0;
        private static Random rnd = new Random();

        private static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> RunAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
                if (rnd.NextDouble() < 0.3)
                {
                    throw new Exception("bad juju");
                }
                return counter.ToString();
            });
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427680/rx-subscribe-with-async-function-and-ignore-errors
            _subject
                .SelectMany(x =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(async () => await RunAsync())
                        )
                 .Subscribe(x =>
                {

                   //no op
                });


            var consumer = new Consumer(_subject);
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                consumer.Consume(CancellationToken.None);

            });
            Console.ReadKey();
            disp.Dispose();

        }
    }



    public class Consumer
    {
        private readonly Subject<string> _subject;

        public Consumer(Subject<string> subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }

        public void Consume(CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _subject.OnNext(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"consumer saw {e.Message}");
                Consume(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result

```
1
consumer saw bad juju
```

Where the Exception is propagated up to the top level class that originally called the `OnNext`, but this only happens 1 time, no other calls are done, despite the fact that `OnNext` is called in a while loop.

However if I change my Subscribe, and jut make the Async/Await code synchronous I get the semmantics I want, what am I doing wrong, why for the `Observable.FromAsync` does it not carry on, and just stops responding to `OnNext`

I can get the semmantics I need by doing this in my `Subscribe` but this seems extremely whack, and is forcing me to make async code sync.

Its like the Exception is not being observed, but I can not see where

```
.Subscribe(x =>
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Any guidance on this would be appreciated

Comment: In the second case, where you use the `Observable.FromAsync` method, does the program crashes after the first exception? Or it continues running, but without outputting anything in the console? Btw be aware that the `Task.Run(() => {consumer...` in both of the examples creates a fire-and-forget task. You won't get any notification if the task fails.

Comment: When using the `Observable.FromAsync` it doesn't crash but simple stops outputting to the console, and it is like the Task is completed already or something, as it never raises the exception again. For the Fire-Forget Task.Run that you mention, yeah that is just demo grade code, real code doesn't do that

Comment: Your `.FromAsync(async () => await RunAsync())` call should be `.FromAsync(() => RunAsync())`. Does that help?

Comment: Nah same issue, I think the real issue is that Exception is raised "in" the stream, which obviously causes the `OnError` to get called, which is not what I want. I need the exception from "inside" the stream to suddenly surface itself "outside" the stream, which is only really possible if the Exception gets raised in the Subscribe. Remember I don't want this Subject to EVER get `OnError` or `OnComplete` so based on that, all work has to be done in the Subscribe. But I know `async await` code in subscribe is anti pattern, and recommended approach is Select->Onservable.Async->Concat->Subscribe