# Reactive Extensions ControlScheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Well i am using ReactiveExtensions eventhandler to handle my application events, i also use ControlScheduler in order to run the handler on the ui thread. However, recently i am getting Cross Thread exception despite using the ControlScheduler and i don't know what is the problem

Code:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<string>(cc, "UiAlertMessage", new ControlScheduler(this)).Subscribe(_ =>
{
    AlertControl.Show(this, Language.Title, _.EventArgs.UppercaseFirst());
});
```

Isn't the `new ControlScheduler(this)` supposed to run the code on the UI Thread so i don't get the Cross Threading exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<string>(cc, "UiAlertMessage")
    .ObserveOn(this)
    .Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        AlertControl.Show(this, Language.Title, _.EventArgs.UppercaseFirst());
    });
```

It is the standard way of dispatching to the scheduler related to the specific control. Passing the control schedular as you have done `subscribes` on the control rather than `observes` on it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done) for this difference between `ObserverOn` and `SubscribeOn`

Note the implementation of `ObserveOn` is from `System..Reactive.Windows.Forms` assembly.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> ObserveOn<TSource>
(this IObservable<TSource> source, Control control)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if (control == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
  else
    return Synchronization.ObserveOn<TSource>(source, (IScheduler) new ControlScheduler(control));
}
```

Comment: Also, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done) for an explanation of `ObserveOn` - the core problem is that you were subscribing on the scheduler instead of observing on it.

Comment: @JamesWorld I'll update the answer to reflect that. Ta