# ConcurrentBag.ToObservable() runs once and completes prematurely

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a static collection, say of tasks to call remote rest api:

```
static ConcurrentBag<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _collection = new ConcurrentBag<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Produce());
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consume());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

One thread adds new items into it:

```
private static void Produce()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var task = HttpClientFactory.Create().GetAsync("http://example.com");
        _collection.Add(task);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

And another thread should process those items:

```
private static void Consume()
{
    _collection.ToObservable()
               .Subscribe(
                   t => Console.WriteLine("++"),
                   ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message),
                   () => Console.WriteLine("Done"));
}
```

But it runs only once and completes prematurely. So output is;

> ++
>
> Done

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I'd expect it to work, if long story short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be interesting if it worked like that... but sadly it doesn't. The `ToObservable` extension method is defined on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface - so it's getting a point-in-time snap shot of the collection.

You need a collection than can be observed, such as [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). With this, you can respond to add events to feed an Rx pipeline (perhaps by wiring the `CollectionChanged` event up with `Observable.FromEventPattern`). Bear in mind that this collection doesn't support concurrent adds.  Such a technique is one way to "enter the monad" (i.e. obtain an `IObservable<T>`).

Equivalent is adding your request payloads to a Subject. Either way, you can then project them into asynchronous requests. So say (for arguments sake), your `Produce` signature looked like this:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Produce(string requestUrl)
```

Then you might construct an observable to convert the requestUrls to async web requests using your `Produce` method like so:

```
var requests = new Subject<string>();
var responses = requests.SelectMany(
    x => Observable.FromAsync(() => Produce(x)));

responses.Subscribe(
               t => Console.WriteLine("++"),
               ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message),
               () => Console.WriteLine("Done"));
```

And submit each request with something like:

```
requests.OnNext("http://myurl");
```

If you need concurrent adds, see [Observable.Synchronize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.synchronize(v=vs.103).aspx).

If you need to control the thread(s) that handle the responses, use `ObserveOn` which I wrote a lengthy explanation of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done/20452901#20452901).

Comment: Added a note about `ObserveOn`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation of a point-in-time snapshot. That's definitely makes sense and seconds what I'm observing.

Comment: Can it use `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` here? I can't have a string because it may be a GET, POST, etc. request. And would be more generic solution. I think I can make it working myself :)

Comment: The thing to bear in mind is that `Task<T>` is really a different async paradigm - so you can, but it's probably worth using `ToObservable()` to convert to an `IObservable<HttpResponseMessage>` - in which case your subject will be a `Subject<IObservable<HttpResponseMessage>>` (i.e. a stream of streams) which can be flattened with a call to `SelectMany(x => x)` to give a flat stream of `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: I'm confused. Produce() is producing new requests. So OnNext() is too. Who is consuming them then? Thanks!

Comment: The subscriber(s) to the stream... in my answer (and your question), it's the code implementing the OnNext handler that is writing to the console.