# RxJava async subscription

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, system.reactive, rx-java

I have a list of tasks which should be handled one-by-one in a new thread and then the result should be displayed in a method by some main thread.
However this doesn't seem to work, the `flatMap` method is invoked in the main thread.

Why does not the `subscribeOn` method handle the "thread switch" in this case?

What would be a better pattern to execute some work in another thread? (except from using `Observable.create` and creating a new thread manually, which is very verbose)

```
List<Task> tasks = ...;
Observable.from(tasks)
          .flatMap(task -> {
                // should be handled in a new thread
                try {
                    return Observable.just(task.call());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error", e);
                }

                return Observable.empty();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(MySchedulers.main())
            .subscribe(this::show); // subscribe called from main thread
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Caveat: I'm not a Java programmer, but C#, so all the weird camel case method names freak me out and confuse me.*

The `subscribeOn` is in the wrong place if you want a new thread for the `flatMap` operation. Insert it between `from` and `flatMap`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done/20452901#20452901) for a full explanation of `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` - it's written for .NET but the principles are the same.

I'm not familiar with tasks in Java, so I'm not sure if your `Task` is like .NET's `Task` and whether `task.call()` is asynchronous and launches its own thread - I guess not from your question since you said "...list of tasks which should be handled one-by-one in *a* new thread".

A `newThread` scheduler uses a new thread *per subscriber* - since `flatMap` will make a single subscription, all `task.call` invocations will be made on the same thread, distinct though that will be from the `from` operator's thread.

If `task.call` actually is asynchronous then the results will come back according to however it introduces concurrency and that will be independent of Rx's semantics.

Either way, the (correctly placed) `observeOn` will cause the results to be passed to `this::show` on the main thread.

Comment: It looks like `Task` here is some custom class that lukstei has created - we don't have a `Task` class with the same name & purpose as a .NET async Task. However, moving `subscribeOn` is right!

Comment: @AdamS yes, you are right, `Task` should represent a single piece of work like a `Runnable`  or a `Callable`

Comment: @james-world thanks for the answer, regarding to the error handling: One single task could fail and should silently be ignored, but I see no advantage of using onError + onErrorResumeNext in contrast to my solution.

Comment: Now that I understand more about what's going on with your `task`, I tend to agree, I'm editing that part out to avoid complicating the answer.