# Rx Example not working

Tags: winforms, system.reactive

I'm trying to follow along with Jonathan Worthington's airport announcement example in [An Event-driven and Reactive Future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VdIQTtRkb8#t=5662)

It compiles.

The problem: `SayGateChange` is never called. I'm new to Rx. I must be leaving something out. What I have here is his code as exactly as I could transcribe it. Sadly, there is no source available online.

`AddGateChange` is supposed to push a new item onto `EventStreams.GateChanged`, which in turn is supposed to be watched by `Announcer.Announcements`, which is supposed to be watched by `SayGateChange`.

I'm in Windows forms, not WPF, if that makes a difference.

I will gladly put it into a console app or LinqPad if that will make it work.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading;

public class frmAnnouncements
{

    Announcer _Announcer = new Announcer();

    ObservableCollection<string> Announcements = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private void frmRx_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateAnnouncements();

        AddGateChange();

    }

    private void AddGateChange()
    {
        EventStreams.GateChanged.OnNext(new GateChanged {
            Destination = "DAL",
            FlightCode = 1503
        });
    }

    private void PopulateAnnouncements()
    {
        _Announcer.Announcements.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(SayGateChange);
    }

    private void SayGateChange(string Message)
    {
        Interaction.MsgBox(Message);
    }

    public class GateChanged
    {
        public string FlightCode;
        public string Destination;
    }

    public class EventStreams
    {
        public static Subject<GateChanged> GateChanged = new Subject<GateChanged>();
    }

    public class Announcer
    {

        public Announcer()
        {
            this.Announcements = EventStreams.GateChanged.Select(e => string.Format("gate change {0} to {1} ", e.FlightCode, e.Destination));
        }


        public IObservable<string> Announcements;
    }
    public frmAnnouncements()
    {
        Load += frmRx_Load;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't like the way Jonathan structures his code - one of the great things about Rx is that it avoids you needing to "jump around" to understand the code. Nevertheless, can you try changing `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` to `.ObserveOn(this)` and see if you get any joy. It worked for me.

Comment: I agree with you about the code shown here in the question. Now that I have it working I'll see how to clean it up. I think he had his code broken out into multiple classes. I packaged the code up like this in part for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Enigmativity stated, using `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is a problem - although without looking at `Interaction.MsgBox` its hard to be 100% certain it's the whole story - I guess it may be in the video, but it's rather long and I didn't watch it all.

The use of `ObservableOnDispatcher()` suggests you have pulled in the wrong nuget package for Rx:

- For WPF applications, use `rx-xaml` (deprecated synonym `rx-wpf`), which provides the extension method `ObserveOnDispatcher()`
- For Winforms applications, use `rx-winforms`, which provides the extension method overload `ObserveOn(Control)`

Both Winforms and WPF have a similar design where the user interface runs on a dedicated thread. In Winforms this is known as the "UI Thread" and in WPF as the "Dispatcher". Although the concept is very similar, the implementation is quite different.

`ObserveOnDispatcher` in WPF will cause the observer notifications `OnXXX` to be invoked on the dispatcher thread.

In WinForms, where you use `ObserveOn(this)`, the `this` will generally be the form itself. For any WinForms control, this will locate the control's `SynchronizationContext` and Post `OnXXX` notifications to that.

Both overloads are smart in that invocations are direct if you happen to be on the correct Dispatcher thread or UI thread already.

I do seem to remember that WinForms  is a lot more tolerant of updating UI off the UI thread - although this problem occurs in WPF too. This isn't a good thing, since it can lead to unpredictable results that are hard to debug. I note that the WinForms `MessageBox.Show` method, for example, doesn't care which thread it is invoked on since it creates it's own window. In general, use of some form of `ObserveOn`/`ObserveOnDispatcher` is always recommended in UI scenarios.

For this reason, it's a good idea to understand how these work in detail. For this, and to learn about the related `SubscribeOn`, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done).

I am surprised that you didn't get an informative `InvalidOperationException` stating that "The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it." I can only think some other part of your code is swallowing exceptions, or you are using WPF code in your app as well and a `Dispatcher` had been created associated with the Winforms UI thread. That code behind `Interaction.MsgBox` is probably to blame for swallowing an error. Either way, I suggest removing `rx-xaml` to avoid confusion.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Rx is so cool...Wish I learned it from the beginning. BTW, `SayGateChange` never got called because `PopulateAnnouncements` was setup wrong as you pointed out, and it was my debugging setting to ignore unhandled exceptions that was swallowing the `InvalidOperationException`. Thanks again.