# The difference between Rx Throttle(...).ObserveOn(scheduler) and Throttle(..., scheduler)

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have the following code:

```
IDisposable subscription = myObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                                       .Subscribe(_ => UpdateUi());
```

As expected, `UpdateUi()` will always execute on the main thread. When I change the code to

```
IDisposable subscription = myObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50))
                                       .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                                       .Subscribe(_ => UpdateUi());
```

`UpdateUI()` will be executed in a background thread.

Why is not `Throttle(...).ObserveOn(scheduler)` equivalent to `Throttle(..., scheduler)`?

Answer (score 5):

In both examples in code you've given `UpdateUi` *will* always be invoked on the scheduler specified by `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`. I can say this with some certainty since `ObserveOn` is a decorator that ensures the `OnNext` handler of subscribers is called on the specified scheduler. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done/20452901#20452901) for an in-depth analysis.

So that said, this is a bit puzzling. Either `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` is not referring to the correct dispatcher scheduler or `UpdateUi` is transitioning off the dispatcher thread. The former is not unprecedented - see https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/768 where others have run into this. I have no idea what the issue was in that case. Perhaps @PaulBetts can weigh in, or you could raise an issue at https://github.com/reactiveui/. Whatever the case, I would carefully check your assumptions here since I would expect this to be a well tested area. Do you have a complete repro?

As to your specific question, the difference between `Throttle(...).ObserveOn(scheduler)` and `Throttle(..., scheduler)` is as follows:

In the first case when `Throttle` is specified without a scheduler it will use the default platform scheduler to introduce the concurrency necessary to run it's timer - on WPF this would use a thread pool thread. So all the throttling will be done on a background thread and, due to the following `ObserveOn` the released events only will be passed to the subscriber on the specified scheduler.

In the case where `Throttle` specifies a scheduler, the throttling is done on that scheduler - both suppressed events and released events will be managed on that scheduler and the subscriber will be called on that same scheduler too.

So either way, the `UpdateUi` will be called on the `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`.

You are best off throttling ui events on the dispatcher in most cases since it's generally more costly to run separate timers on a background thread and pay for the context switch if only a fraction of events are going to make it through the throttle.

So, just to check you haven't run into an issue with `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`, I would try specifying the scheduler or `SynchronizationContext` explicitly via another means. How to do this will depend on the platform you are on - `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is hopefully available, or use a suitable `ObserveOn` overload. There are options for controls, syncronizationcontexts and schedulers given the correct `Rx` libraries are imported.

Comment: Thank you, turns out there seems to be an issue with my `MainThreadScheduler` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28827962/167251)

Comment: I've just found out, [there's a bit more about the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69877166/1768303).

Answer (score 5):

After some investigation I believe this is caused by a different version of Rx being used run time than I expect (I develop a plugin for a third-party application).

I'm not sure why, but it seems that the default `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` fails to initialize correctly. The default instance is a `WaitForDispatcherScheduler` ([source](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/WaitForDispatcherScheduler.cs)). All functions in this class rely `attemptToCreateScheduler`:

```
    IScheduler attemptToCreateScheduler()
    {
        if (_innerScheduler != null) return _innerScheduler;
        try {
            _innerScheduler = _schedulerFactory();
            return _innerScheduler;
        } catch (Exception) {
            // NB: Dispatcher's not ready yet. Keep using CurrentThread
            return CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance;
        }
    }
```

What seems to happen in my case is that `_schedulerFactory()` throws, resulting in `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance` to be returned instead.

By manually initializing the `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` to `new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current)` behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've just bumped into an issue that first led me to this question and then to some experimenting.

It turns out, `Throttle(timeSpan, scheduler)` is clever enough to "cancel" an already scheduled debounced event `X`, in case the source emits another event `Y` *before* `X` gets observed. Thus, only `Y` will be eventually observed (provided it's the last debounced event).

With `Throttle(timeSpan).ObserveOn(scheduler)`, both `X` and `Y` will be observed.

So, conceptually, that's an important difference between the two approaches. Sadly, Rx.NET docs are scarce, but I believe this behavior is by design and it makes sense to me.

To illustrate this with an example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HBVcwy)):

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    static async Task ThrottleWithScheduler()
    {
        WriteLine($"\n{nameof(ThrottleWithScheduler)}\n");

        var sc = new CustomSyncContext();
        var scheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(sc);
        var subj = new BehaviorSubject<string>("A");

        subj
            .Do(v => WriteLine($"Emitted {v} on {sc.Elapsed}ms"))
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), scheduler)
            .Subscribe(v => WriteLine($"Observed {v} on {sc.Elapsed}ms"));

        await Task.Delay(100);
        subj.OnNext("B");
        await Task.Delay(200);
        subj.OnNext("X");
        await Task.Delay(550);
        subj.OnNext("Y");

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        WriteLine("Finished!");
    }

    static async Task ThrottleWithObserveOn()
    {
        WriteLine($"\n{nameof(ThrottleWithObserveOn)}\n");

        var sc = new CustomSyncContext();
        var scheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(sc);
        var subj = new BehaviorSubject<string>("A");

        subj
            .Do(v => WriteLine($"Emitted {v} on {sc.Elapsed}ms"))
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .ObserveOn(scheduler)
            .Subscribe(v => WriteLine($"Observed {v} on {sc.Elapsed}ms"));

        await Task.Delay(100);
        subj.OnNext("B");
        await Task.Delay(200);
        subj.OnNext("X");
        await Task.Delay(550);
        subj.OnNext("Y");

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        WriteLine("Finished!");
    }

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await ThrottleWithScheduler();
        await ThrottleWithObserveOn();
    }
}

class CustomSyncContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    public long Elapsed { get { lock (_sw) { return _sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; } } }
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object? state)
    {
        WriteLine($"Scheduled on {Elapsed}ms");
        Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(
            continuationAction: _ =>
            {
                WriteLine($"Executed on {Elapsed}ms");
                d(state);
            },
            continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ThrottleWithScheduler

Emitted A on 18ms
Emitted B on 142ms
Emitted X on 351ms
Scheduled on 861ms
Emitted Y on 907ms
Executed on 972ms
Scheduled on 1421ms
Executed on 1536ms
Observed Y on 1539ms
Finished!

ThrottleWithObserveOn

Emitted A on 4ms
Emitted B on 113ms
Emitted X on 315ms
Scheduled on 837ms
Emitted Y on 886ms
Executed on 951ms
Observed X on 953ms
Scheduled on 1391ms
Executed on 1508ms
Observed Y on 1508ms
Finished!
```