# Execute OnNext on a Main Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I am trying to implement a kind of device driver in a reactive style. The idea is to have a thread fully occupied in exchanging and processing data from the device, and have a `Subject` to expose output data by firing `OnNext` events in the device's thread. I want my `OnNext` methods to be evaluated in the Main Thread ID 1. This is crucial for me, as, in fact, I need to collect data simultaneously from several devices. The timing of each new data sample is almost random. The Main Thread, or let's say Main `Scheduler`, will be occupied with this complex timeline of data of different sorts. That is why I need to be sure that `OnNext` is observed on the Main Thread.

Look at this toy example

```
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

class RxDeviceDriver
{
    public Subject<int> EventSubject;
    public RxDeviceDriver()
    {
        EventSubject = new Subject<int>();

        var driverThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opened device's thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved new value {0}, thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                EventSubject.OnNext(i++);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });
        driverThread.Start();

    }
}

class ToyTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Starting on main thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        RxDeviceDriver newDevice = new RxDeviceDriver();

        Thread.Sleep(2500);

        newDevice.EventSubject
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Subscribe(v => Console.WriteLine("Processing value {0} on thread {1}", v, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

    }
}
```

It makes the following output:

```
Starting on main thread 1
Opened device's thread 10
Recieved new value 1, thread 10
Recieved new value 2, thread 10
Recieved new value 3, thread 10
Recieved new value 4, thread 10
Processing value 4 on thread 12
Recieved new value 5, thread 10
Processing value 5 on thread 12
```

It seems that `Scheduler.Default` is trying to be fast and reduce the concurrency, and this is equal to `ThreadPoolScheduler` in fact. I can have some control over observing thread, and I can even choose my own `EventLoopScheduler`, but this is not what I need, a Main Thread. A similar question was asked [for WinForms application and UI thread synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011011/execute-onnext-in-parallel-but-sync-subscription-with-ui-thread). The working answer is to pass `SynchronzationContext` of the UI as an argument of the `ObserveOn` method. But in my case, where this layer of the model should not have any concern about the UI and has a null `SynchronzationContext` value, how can I force to execute `OnNext` on the Main Thread?

Maybe if you have any other ideas on how to implement this kind of driver in a reactive style, they are also welcome.

Comment: I think you are overanalyzing this. You can make your own "event loop" with a blockingCollection that messages can be posted to. Or use something like DataFlow. Or use a [LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0) with a limit of one.