# Rx.NET 'Distinct' to get the lastest value?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm new to Rx and I'm trying to make a GUI to display stock market data. The concept is a bit like [ReactiveTrader](https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/ReactiveTrader), but I'll need to display the whole "depth", i.e., all prices and their buy/sell quantities in the market instead of only the "top level" of the market buy/sells, sorting by price.

The data structure for each "price level" is like this:

```
public class MarketDepthLevel
{
    public int MarketBidQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int MarketAskQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

And underneath the GUI, a socket listens to network updates and return them as an Observable:

```
IObservable<MarketDepthLevel> MarketPriceLevelStream;
```

Which after transformed into a ReactiveList, eventually bound to a DataGrid.

The transformation would basically choose the latest updates of each price level, and sort them by price. So I come up with something like this:

```
    public IReactiveDerivedList<MarketDepthLevel> MarketDepthStream
    {
        get
        {
            return MarketDepthLevelStream
                .Distinct(x => x.Price)
                .CreateCollection()
                .CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, orderer: (x, y) => y.Price.CompareTo(x.Price));
        }
    }
```

But there are problems:

1. When 'Distinct' sees a same price as appeared before, it **discards the new one**, but I need the **new one to replace the old ones** (as they contain the lasted MarketBidQuantity/MarketAskQuantity)
2. It seems a bit clumsy to CreateCollection/CreateDerivedColleciton

Any thoughts on solving these (especially the 1st problem)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just group the items and then project each group to be the last item in the group:

```
return MarketDepthLevelStream
    .GroupBy(x => x.Price, (key, items) => items.Last());
```

Comment: I maybe misreading the question, but I don' t think this will work; `Last()` isn't going to produce a value until the source stream completes, and I assume since Rx is in play that the requirement is for display from a continuously updated stream.

Comment: @JamesWorld The question doesn't seem to describe the desired behavior one way or another, with respect to that point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to project a stream of `MarketDepthLevel` updates in a list of the latest bid/ask quantities for each level (in finance parlance, this is a type of *ladder*). The ladder is held as a `ReactiveList` bound the UI. ([`ObserveOn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done/20452901#20452901) may be required, although `ReactiveList` handles this in most cases I believe)

Here's an example ladder snapped from http://ratesetter.com, where the "Price" is expressed as a percentage (Rate), and the bid/ask sizes by the amount lenders want and borrowers need at each price level:

[image: RateSetter Ladder]

At this point, I begin to get slightly lost. I'm confused as to why you need any further Rx operators, since you could simply `Subscribe` to the update stream as is and have the handler update a fixed list data-bound to a UI. Doesn't each new event simply need to be added to the `ReactiveList` if it's a new price, or replace an existing entry with a matching price? Imperative code to do this is fine if it's the last step in the chain to the UI.

There is only value in doing this in the Rx stream itself if you need to convert the `MarketDepthLevelStream` into a stream of ladders. That could be useful, but you don't mention this need.

Such a need could be driven by either the desire to multicast the stream to many subscribers, and/or because you have further transformations or projections you need to make on the ladders.

Bear in mind, if the ladder is large, then working with whole ladder updates in the UI might give you performance issues - in many cases, individual updates into a mutable structure like a `ReactiveList` are a practical way to go.

If working with a stream of ladders *is* a requirement, then look to `Observable.Scan`. This is the work-horse operator in Rx that maintains local state. It is used for any form of running aggregate - such as a running total, average etc., or in this case, a ladder.

Now if all you need is the static list described above, I am potentially off on a massive detour here, but it's a useful discussion so...

You'll want to think carefully about the type used for the ladder aggregate - you need to be concious of how down-stream events would be consumed. It's likely to need an *immutable* collection type so that things don't get weird for subscribers (each event should be in effect a static snapshot of the ladder). With [immutable collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx), it may be important to think about memory efficiency.

Here's a simple example of how a ladder stream might work, using an immutable collection from nuget pre-release package [`System.Collections.Immutable`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx):

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<ImmutableSortedDictionary<decimal, MarketDepthLevel>>
        ToLadder(this IObservable<MarketDepthLevel> source)
    {
        return source.Scan(ImmutableSortedDictionary<decimal, MarketDepthLevel>.Empty,
            (lastLadder, depthLevel) =>
                lastLadder.SetItem(depthLevel.Price, depthLevel));
    }
}
```

The `ToLadder` extension method creates an empty immutable ladder as the seed aggregate, and each successive `MarketDepthLevel` event produces a new update ladder. *You may want to see if `ImmutableSortedSet` is sufficient.*

You would probably want to wrap/project this into your own type, but hopefully you get the idea.

Ultimately, this still leaves you with the challenge of updating a UI - and as mentioned before now you are stuck with the whole ladder, meaning you have to bind a whole ladder every time, or convert it back to a stream of individual updates - and it's getting way to off topic to tackle that here...!