# Branching observables and concurrency configuration in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Consider this example:

```
observable
  .Where(somePredicate)
  .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
  .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
  .Subscribe(x => { });
```

Is the `Where()` executed in the task pool, or only the subscribe func?

Following on:

```
var newObservable = observable.
  .Where(somePredicate)
  .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
  .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default);

newObservable.Subscribe(x => { });
newObservable.Subscribe(x => { });
```

In this example, do both subscriptions retain the concurrency settings of `newObservable`? In that sense, can the creator of an observable define a different concurrency default (vs the Rx default) and pass it on to users of the observable, unless overriden?

Edit:

Now, if:

```
newObservable
  .Where(somePredicate2)
  .Subscribe(x => { })
```

Is this now executed on the task pool too?

Comment: As for #1, everything gets executed on the threadpool. Your application would block while waiting for events if `Where` executed on the main thread.

Comment: There's a great introduction to concurrency in Rx [here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SchedulingAndThreading)

Comment: As for #2 check [ObserveOn and SubscribeOn - where the work is being done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so if I understood it correctly, the `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` apply to the part of the stream after the calls. Correct? If you can write a short summary (the other thread is great for an in-depth understanding) as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, see my fuller answer [ObserveOn and SubscribeOn - where the work is being done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done) for details, but:

Fundamentally, you need to understand that `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` are decorators that only affect the downstream behaviour of an observable (the callers of `Subscribe` and receivers of `OnXXX`) - they don't magically change the internal behaviour of the `observable` they wrap.

- Where the `Where` executes is mostly dependent on the implementation of `observable`, which you don't share. Certainly, `ObserveOn` has no impact and `SubscribeOn` may have an impact *if and only if* the `observable` implementation yields events on the subscriber's thread - but don't use it to try and control this, that's not what it is for.
- In the follow on, I think you are asking if subscribers to `newObservable` have the behaviour of `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn`? In which case, yes. Again I suspect taking the time to read the above answer will make this very obvious.
- When you add the `Where` on the `newObserable`, the thread on which the subscriber is called won't be affected - and it's purely the implementation of `Where` that determines this, nothing to do with any upstream `ObserveOn` or `SubscribeOn`.

Bottom line, there is a summary in the top of my answer - that's the best TL;DR I have for you.

Comment: I'm still rather confused. I'll read the longer answer again when my head is not spinning and retort :)