# ConfigureAwait for IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive

I'm experiencing a deadlock when I use blocking code with `Task.Wait()`, waiting an `async` method that inside awaits an Rx LINQ query.

This is an example:

```
public void BlockingCode() 

{

    this.ExecuteAsync().Wait();

}

public async Task ExecuteAsync() 

{

    await this.service.GetFooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //This is the RX query that doesn't support ConfigureAwaitawait 
    await this.service.Receiver
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x == "foo")
      .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

}
```

So, my question is if there is any equivalent for ConfigureAwait on awaitable IObservable to ensure that the continuation is not resumed on the same `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: You should NEVER EVER EVER use `Task.Wait()` and you should avoid using `Task.Result`. They will eventually cause a deadlock unless you know what you are doing...but if you did...you wouldn't use them either.

Comment: I know that thing, and that's why in my example I'm adding ConfigureAwait(false), which prevents any deadlock because it doesn't resume on the same SynchronizationContext than before the await call.
The issue is that ConfigureAwait(false) doesn't exist for awaiting Observables...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.observeon%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I also tried that with ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default). But what continues in another thread is the delegate inside the Subscribe method.
I'm not sure if what follows the await block also continues there.

Like:

    //Here I'm on a specific Sinchronization Context
    await observable.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(()    => {
        //This goes for sure in another thread.
    });

    //Here, on what Synchronization Context am I? I don't want to be on the same one before awaiting...

Comment: Then I can't help you with `this.service.Receiver`. Depends entirely on the implementation.

Comment: Here are some ways to avoid deadlocks with async-await http://www.nedstoyanov.com/async-await-deadlock/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to comprehend what "awaiting an Observable" means. Check out [this](http://log.paulbetts.org/rx-and-await-some-notes/). So, semantically, your code

```
await this.service.Receiver
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x == "foo")
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

is equivalent to

```
await this.service.Receiver
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x == "foo")
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .LastAsync()
    .ToTask();
```

(Note that there is some kind of redundance here, calling `FirstOrDefaultAsync`and `LastAsync` but that's no problem).

So there you got your task (it can take an additional `CancellationToken` if available). You may now use `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I don't understand why do I need to do .LastAsync().ToTask() instead of .ToTask() directly.

Comment: You are right, you don't have to, since ToTask already takes the last value in the sequence. I just wanted to make clear what code is equivalent to "awaiting an observable", and put emphasis on the fact that it is always the last value being taken.

Comment: Noted that you can pass cancellation token with `ToTask()` to unsubscribe the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigureAwait` is not directly related to awaiters themselves, rather it is a functionality of the TPL to configure how `Task` should complete. It's problematic because this TPL method doesn't return a new `Task`, so you can't compose it with a conversion to an observable.

Rx itself is basically free-threaded. You can control the threads used during subscription and events with far finer control than `Tasks` - see here for more on this: [ObserveOn and SubscribeOn - where the work is being done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451939/observeon-and-subscribeon-where-the-work-is-being-done/20452901#20452901)

It's hard to fix your code because you don't provide a small but complete working example - however, the built in functions in Rx won't ever try to marshall to a particular thread unless you specifically tell them to with one of the above operators.

If you combine an operator like `Observable.FromAsync` to convert the `Task` to an observable, you can use `Observable.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)` to start the `Task` off the current `SynchronizationContext`.

Here's a gist to play with (designed for LINQPad, runs with nuget package rx-main): https://gist.github.com/james-world/82c3cc39babab7870f6d

Comment: I think that misses the point of the question. It is not about the context in which a value is observed but rather about the context in which the  continuation will be scheduled.

Comment: I don't think it does miss the point. I'm saying that FromAsync and SubscribeOn give you the chance to control the context in which the continuation is scheduled. (And in the article you linked, Paul mentions using StartAsync and Defer - which FromAsync wraps - in much the same way)

Comment: OP is trying to avoid a deadlock due to marshalling back to the SynchronizationContext in which the task is started (ala ConfigureAwait(true)), so ensuring you *aren't* on a context when the task is kicked off solves the problem.

Comment: By the task that is "kicked off", you refer to `ExecuteAsync`? Of course, ensuring that is is already started on some thread pool thread solves this particular problem, but that will only hide the real problem in `ExecuteAsync`, i.e. the continuation is scheduled on the original context.

Comment: ...which is why I asked for a complete working program, best to solve the problem at that point, not in the Rx. I could have been clearer about that I guess. This is very much a workaround.

Comment: If `ExecuteAsync` is some library-code then it might still be a good idea to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` throughout it so I hope my answer will be helpful. But I agree wrt. a complete working programm since the bug is probably in `GetFooAsync()` or `sender.Receiver` doing something upon subscription that deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and James for the help and detailed information. It was very useful. I will combine the suggestions and use SubscribeOn for the origin of the Stream, which is generated with Observable.FromAsync, and I will add the .ToTask().ConfigureAwait(false) on the consumer code just to add extra safety.

Comment: Which is the difference in this case by using Scheduler.Default versus NewThreadScheduler.Default? I have doubts of which scheduler is used in the case of Scheduler.Default.